# Google spreadsheet - incrementing counter for item every time it is selected from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have google spreadsheet with a column of different products.  In another sheet I have a column where each cell contains a dropdown menu populated by the products in the other sheet.  I want to program my spreadsheet so that every time a product is selected in the dropdown menu a counter next to the product is incremented.  How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share an example spreadsheet. Is hard to work out what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, with this piece of code it is possible:

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "A2") {
    var sCounter = e.source.getRange("B2");
    var counter = sCounter.getValue();
    if(counter === 0) {
      counter = 1;
    } else {
      counter ++;
    }
    sCounter.setValue(counter);
  }        
}
```

### Example

I've created an example file for you: [Dropdown Counter](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdGhGYmREVU10M19FUjlra2tuZEp4NkE&usp=sharing)

### Remark

This script will only execute if the cell is active in `A2`.